# Oracle Trigger ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-04098

I am trying to create a simple trigger in an oracle 10g database. This script to Create the trigger runs clean.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER newAlert
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Alerts
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Users (userID, firstName, lastName, password) VALUES ('how', 'im', 'testing', 'this trigger')
  END;           
/
```

But when I run:

```
INSERT INTO Alerts(observationID, dateSent, message, dateViewed) VALUES (3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Alert: You have exceeded the Max Threshold', NULL);
```

to activate the trigger, I get this error message:

> ORA-04098: trigger 'JMD.NEWALERT' is invalid and failed re-validation
>   (0 rows affected)

I don't understand whats causes this error. Do you know what causes this error? Or why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

-David

Comment: Also I have run `INSERT INTO Users (userID, firstName, lastName, password) VALUES ('how', 'im', 'testing', 'this trigger')` and it works fine.

Comment: what is your table structure for `Users` and `Alerts` tables?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Oracle will try to recompile invalid objects as they are referred to. Here the trigger is invalid, and every time you try to insert a row it will try to recompile the trigger, and fail, which leads to the ORA-04098 error.

You can `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'NEWALERT'` to see what error(s) the trigger actually gets and why it won't compile. In this case it appears you're missing a semicolon at the end of the `insert` line:

```
INSERT INTO Users (userID, firstName, lastName, password)
VALUES ('how', 'im', 'testing', 'this trigger')
```

So make it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER newAlert
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Alerts
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Users (userID, firstName, lastName, password)
        VALUES ('how', 'im', 'testing', 'this trigger');
  END;           
/
```

If you get a compilation warning when you do that you can do `show errors` if you're in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, or query `user_errors` again.

Of course, this assumes your `Users` tables does have those column names, and they are all `varchar2`... but presumably you'll be doing something more interesting with the trigger really.

Comment: Thank you so much! As a java developer I am especially embarrassed that my mistake was a missing semicolon. Haha

Comment: I didn't know about the select clause for the trigger error, +1 for that, and also you can run `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER trigger_name;` for check errors on the trigger's definition http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04098.php

Answer (score 7):

**Cause**: A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was found to be invalid. This also means that compilation/authorization failed for the trigger.

**Action**: Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors, disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

**Syntax**

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_Name DISABLE;

ALTER TRIGGER trigger_Name ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case, this error is raised due to sequence was not created..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  J.SOME_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```