# Trigger invalid and revalidation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have executed the next query and got "trigger invalid and revalidation" error. What is wrong in this query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
  BEFORE
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE OF sal, deptno OR
    DELETE
  ON emp
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
    WHEN UPDATING('sal') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating salary');
    WHEN UPDATING('deptno') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating department ID');
    WHEN DELETING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleting');
  END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: What is the exact error returned?

Comment: The trigger seems to be created fine for me. Have you tried following the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668507/oracle-trigger-ora-04098-trigger-is-invalid-and-failed-re-validation

As an aside, I believe you are using the wrong column names in your case statement i.e. 'salary' and 'sal' should refer to the same column, same for department_id and deptno

Comment: This appears to be an almost-perfect copy of this example from the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible test case.  Your code contained cut'n'paste errors: your column names in the UPDATING clauses come from the newish HR schema whereas your trigger is built on the venerable SCOTT schema.  But as those are strings it won't cause compilation errors.  So, either your actual trigger code is different from that posted here or your table's structure is different from what your trigger suggests.