# Trigger — is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create this simple trigger :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trig 
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON empcopy 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (NEW.EID > 0) 
  DECLARE 
  sal_diff number; 
  BEGIN 

 sal_diff := :NEW.salary  - :OLD.salary; 
 dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.salary); 
 dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.salary); 
 dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff); 
 COMMIT;
  END; 
  /
```

on execution it gives the result as:

```
   Trigger created
```

But when I update my table the following result is obtained:

```
  update empcopy
  set salary=salary+5000;
```

after execution:

```
  error at line 1 
  ORA-0498:triiger 'HR.MY_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation.
```

Comment: Looks like there is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668507/oracle-trigger-ora-04098-trigger-is-invalid-and-failed-re-validation

Comment: Not working with this solution.

Comment: @Jaskunwarsingh This answer has been updated with a full working example.  Please run the provided example and let me know if you receive an error.  Also including your oracle version is often helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `COMMIT` without using a `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in your `DECLARE` block.
If the database allowed committing in row-level triggers, this could enable committing part of the rows in a statement before the others had been evaluated and would disrupt the statement as a unit--all rows in an individual statement should complete their change and be committed together.
If you were to use an AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in this trigger, this would allow the trigger to execute new `UPDATE`s, `DELETE`s, etc in a transaction independent from other active DML changes in the open transaction.
**But note**, in you're case, your `TRIGGER` isn't actually executing any mutational `DML`, nor even any reads, so you don't need a `COMMIT` at all.  All you need to do is drop your `COMMIT` as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trig
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON empcopy
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.EID > 0)
  DECLARE
    sal_diff number;
  BEGIN

    sal_diff := :NEW.salary  - :OLD.salary;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff);
  END;
/
```

I would however suggest a couple other changes as well.
As other triggers can also change the `NEW` value, you might consider making this an `AFTER TRIGGER`, to only log the final state.
Also this trigger will not log any `DELETE`s, since `DELETE`s will all have a `NULL` `:NEW.EID`.  I'd suggest either dropping the `AFTER DELETE` if logging `DELETE`s is not intended, or handling `DELETE`s separately via a `CASE WHEN DELETING` statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIG
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPCOPY
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    SAL_DIFF NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    CASE WHEN DELETING
      THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Log the delete here if you want.');
      WHEN (:NEW.EID > 0)
      THEN
        SAL_DIFF := COALESCE(:NEW.SALARY, 0) - COALESCE(:OLD.SALARY, 0);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.SALARY);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.SALARY);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Salary difference: ' || SAL_DIFF);
    ELSE NULL;
    END CASE;
  END;
/
```

Also DBMS_OUTPUT is transient logging.  In case you want to keep a record of changes to `EMPCOPY` more permanently, Oracle has tools available to automate and control change-tracking in your data, such as audit trail and FGA.

**EDIT: examples below.**

Create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPCOPY(
  EID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  SALARY NUMBER
);
Table EMPCOPY created.
```

Then create the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIG
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPCOPY
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    SAL_DIFF NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    CASE WHEN DELETING
      THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Log the delete here if you want.');
      WHEN (:NEW.EID > 0)
      THEN
        SAL_DIFF := COALESCE(:NEW.SALARY, 0) - COALESCE(:OLD.SALARY, 0);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.SALARY);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.SALARY);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Salary difference: ' || SAL_DIFF);
    ELSE NULL;
    END CASE;
  END;
/
Trigger MY_TRIG compiled
```

Then test it:

```
SQL> --Should not log, EMPID is not greater than zero.
SQL> INSERT INTO EMPCOPY VALUES (-13, 50000);
1 row inserted.
SQL> --Should log, EMPID is greater than zero.
SQL> INSERT INTO EMPCOPY VALUES (1919, 75000);
Old salary: 
New salary: 75000
Salary difference: 75000
1 row inserted.
SQL> -- The statement you provided.  This should log for EMPID=1919 but not EMPID=-13
SQL> update empcopy
  2  set salary=salary+5000;
Old salary: 75000
New salary: 80000
Salary difference: 5000
2 rows updated.
SQL> -- This should log a PLACEHOLDER value for each row on delete.
SQL> DELETE FROM EMPCOPY;
Log the delete here if you want.
Log the delete here if you want.
2 rows deleted.
```

Comment: @Jaskunwarsingh what is the error?  And which version of the trigger are you using,  BEFORE or AFTER?  Can you please post the code you used to create the trigger and the code that throws the error?  It would help to see what is being executed to evaluate things. Also what version of oracle are you using?  Thanks