# ORA-04098: trigger 'PRAS.B' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following query,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_salary_changes
BEFORE  INSERT ON marks 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    sal_diff number;
BEGIN 
    sal_diff:=:NEW.sub1-:OLD.sub1;
    dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.sub1); 
    dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.sub1); 
    dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff); 
END;
```

When I try to run this it throws,

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'PRAS.B' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

NAME        TYPE            SEQUENCE      LINE     POSITION  TEXT    ATTRIBUTE  MESSAGE_NUMBER

```
B        TRIGGER        1        9      38        PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.SUB1' must be declared ERROR   201

B   TRIGGER 2   9   2   PL/SQL: Statement ignored   ERROR   0

B   TRIGGER 3   10  41  PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.SUB1' must be declared   ERROR   201

B   TRIGGER 4   10  2   PL/SQL: Statement ignored   ERROR   0
```

Comment: On insert I think old has no value, I don't know if this is the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668507/oracle-trigger-ora-04098-trigger-is-invalid-and-failed-re-validation

Comment: thank you i found out the problem. A trigger which was created earlier was causing this problem.